# Insert a pandas dataframe into a SQLite table / update a table with a dataframe

Tags: python, sql, pandas, sqlite, dataframe

So I have a dataframe imported from excel and an SQL Table with matching columns. So far I have been updating the table using the columns as lists:

```py
Schedule_Frame = DataFrame(Sheet_Schedule)
Column_ID = Schedule_Frame['ID']
Column_list = list(Column_ID)

for i in range(len(Column_list)):
    miCursor.execute("UPDATE SCHEDULE SET ID=? WHERE rowid=?",(Column_list[i],i))
```

However, since what I have in SQLite is a table that matches my dataframe columns, I am sure that there is a way to update the whole SQLite table using my frame. Any ideas how to do it?

Answer (score 16):

I think you're using `sqlite3` package to access your SQLite database. How about using [SQLAlchemy](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) – which operates well with Pandas' data structures – to access the database?

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///<replace_this_with_path_to_db_file>', echo=False)
```

Then doing:

```
Schedule_Frame.to_sql('SCHEDULE', con=engine, if_exists='append')
```

**Edit**: Example code

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('sqlite:///my.db', echo=False)
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[1,2]], columns=['a', 'b'])

df.to_sql('mytable', con=engine, if_exists='append')
```

In sqlite3 CLI:

```
sqlite> select * from 'mytable';
0|1|2
1|1|2
```

Resources:

- [SQLite engine configuration in SQLAlchemy](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/engines.html#sqlite)
- [DataFrame.to_sql](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! When I go to it and insert my code as:

     from sqlalchemy import create_engine
     engine = create_engine('sqlite://C:/Users/Javier/Desktop/Holidays 
     Tool/Scheduler RES', echo=False)

     Schedule_Frame.to_sql('SCHEDULE', con=engine, if_exists='append')

I get the following error:

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''


Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure your path points to the database file (usually database file has a `.db` suffix)? I ran the code I suggested with a dummy DataFrame and it all worked out perfectly. Your error suggest though that your schema might be different to the DataFrame's schema.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I used it as your and it worked. The only error I am getting now it is regarding index:
sqlite3.OperationalError: table SCHEDULE has no column named index
Do you know if I can change something in the code so it doesnt try to add an index column to my table in the db??

Answer (score 0):

You can append a frame to an existing SQLite database using `sqlite3` too.

```py
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('<path to DB>')
df.to_sql('schedule', conn, if_exists='append')
conn.close()
```

OP's actual problem was updating an existing table. In that case, `sqlite3` is useful too. For example, instead of the iterative UPDATE to update an existing table with one column, you can use UPDATE FROM statement.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(...)                           # dataframe in memory
with sqlite3.connect('<path to DB>') as conn:
    df.to_sql('temporary_table', conn)           # write df into the database
    conn.execute("""
    UPDATE schedule 
    SET ID = temp.column_list
    FROM (SELECT column_list, row_id FROM temporary_table) AS temp 
    WHERE schedule.row_id = temp.row_id;
    """)                                         # update the schedule table in the database
    conn.execute('DROP TABLE temporary_table')   # drop df from the database
```